# Is it any more secure to use a HTML form instead of a javascript popup?

Tags: tls, javascript

Assuming both use session authentication, token validation and forced https:

Is there any difference in security between submitting data via a JS popup <> ajax endpoint, and a standard web page form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Same-Origin Policy](https://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2) does not differentiate between HTML and JavaScript in the context of data-access.  An HTML form exists within the DOM within the website's context, and JavaScript is bound to this same context. In both implementations [Cross-site Scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) can be used to undermine the Same-Origin Policy and obtain sensitive information.

Comment: Thank you - it's what I thought (and was hoping). I only really mentioned HTTPS to keep mitm concerns out of the picture.